# Debian Jenkins Slaves failing to build

Tags: java, jenkins

I have set up a few debian slaves for a windows Jenkins server. They are x84 and x64. I simply want them to build the code. We took some time to set up the distrubuted builds on jenkins, and the slaves are targeted. When we queue a build, the build immediately fails with

```
    Building remotely on debian_x64 in workspace/var/jenkins/workspace/com.ipti.common - linux
Updating http://10.230.57.197/svn/pickmax_express/Source/Development/java/com.ipti.common  at revision '2014-07-31T12:50:29.546 -0500'
At revision 1799
no change for http://10.230.57.197/svn/pickmax_express/Source/Development/java/com.ipti.common since the previous build
Triggering linux
linux completed with result FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

After some searching we found that the /var/jenkins folder was missing... short while later we had added the user to the sudo group, and granted rw to the folder. Queuing the build again now downloads the source code, but ultimately results in the same message. No logs, no description of the problem, nothing. Does anyone know what could cause this?

A bit more:
Used java webstart to install the slave client
Its running with elevated rights
Not installed as a service, as the option to crashes immediately with a "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.Error Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread.

Comment: what kinda job is this? are you executing a set of commands on the debian slave? If so make sure that all the commands run without any error. Even though if a command failure will not affect your rest of the code and it might build successfully but the end result will always be marked as a failure. If I could see what the job is I could tell more. Don't you see anything in the slave log (which gives you the console output)?

Comment: I was able to figure this out Waman. The issue was that the master was funneling it's JAVA_HOME variable to the unit machines. We had use a provided settings XML which was preventing meaningful messages from appearing in the output. After providing the correct JAVA_HOME path tot he unit platforms, I was able to debug the rest of the hiccups.